# Creating own custom theme in Magento2

Tags: theme, magento-2.1

I've created `magento2` custom theme and I can see it in `Content->Themes`.

But as I'm going to `stores->configuration->general->design`, I am not finding my `theme`.

Could any one suggest what should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

magento 2.1 Theme Selection Move to Magento Admin -> Content-> Design -> Configuration

Then, Edit and choose Your Theme.

Comment: Thanks.. It worked. But as I'm opening that theme only header is displaying there, Is there any other thing I have to do?

Comment: you need add  home page content then only show in front end  via admin --> Content -> Page -> Homepage-> Edit Add some Content, then  clear cache now check it , now added content view in home page